# IntelliJ IDEA internal error "Equal objects must have equal hashcodes" (by Trove)

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to build my project, more often than not compilation fails with the following error message:

> Error:java: Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's documentation. object #1 =sdk references (class org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsSdkReferencesTableImpl$JpsSdkReferencesTableRole), hashCode=16097604; object #2 =sdk references (class org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsSdkReferencesTableImpl$JpsSdkReferencesTableRole), hashCode=16097604

Sometimes I try building again and it succeeds, other times I have to resort to restarting the IDE.  This used to happen with IDEA 2019.2, it is continuing with 2019.3.

Does anyone know what can be done from my side to avoid this internal IDE error?  Any hints, suggestions, workarounds?

Update: happened again, (4 hours later,) restarting the IDE did not help, I had to invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Looks like a bug that needs to be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA. There is one similar open bug reported (submitted privately by a user, so I can't provide a link). It would help if you [file another issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) and provide the sample project to reproduce it, plus the logs (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...).

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue.  I am using IntelliJ 2019.3 as well.  I only started seeing it when I changed my Project language level up from JDK 8 to JDK 11.  I hope that IntelliJ patches this bug ASAP...